# How to remove key in graphs

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

How should i remove key in graphs. I am using `mpAndroid` library version 2.0.9
[image]

Skack-overflow has generated the link of the image as it is not allowing me to add the image

Answer (score 1):

try

```
chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following line:

```
lineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```